# Call method when Application Closes

Tags: java, android, android-studio

**I know this is asked many times, but I want to clear things up**

In which activity should I place `onDestroy()`? Say I am in the `MainActivity` A and I move to activity B. But then I close the application while being on activity B. Does the `onDestroy()` method in `MainActivity` A get called? Or should I put an `onDestroy()` method for every activity in the application? Or is there any other way around this?

I have tried reading documentation and reading other answers but they don't help me clearly.

Comment: Hi , Do you want to call some method when user swipe out the application from recent apps ?

Comment: yes ! thats what i want to do

Comment: I have added a answer , please try it and mark is as right answer If it something you were looking for,that will help others too ! In case you face any issue please comment below the answer !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are **multiple ways** to do so , Here I have **mentioned the most reliable way I have found during development carrier** . You need to **create a Service** which can keep an `eye whether application got closed or not`, so here I have mentioned the code  !

1.**Create Service** , as you can see below there is a **new class named as** `MyService`, this needs to **extended to Service**.

```html
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

public class MyService extends Service {
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        Log.d(getClass().getName(), "App just got removed from Recents!");
    }


}
```

2.Add this `entry to Manifest.xml` as below ...

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.TestApplication">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name=".MyService" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

3.This is Just a **Service that will run in background** , but we **need to start it once the application starts** , so in your `launcher activity` start it like below.

```html
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        
        Intent stickyService = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
        startService(stickyService);

    }
}
```

4.**Service will start** and whenever U**ser will Swipe out the application from recent** , the function `onTaskRemoved` will be **called automatically** , in this function you can put your required work or code to be executed at the application end !

Comment: worked perfectly and a Very clear explanation. Thank you for taking time to help!

Comment: I am glad , i helped !